# How to I do multiple columns partitioning with the rows being duplicated?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a set of SQL Stored procedure to use partitioning for my ranking to get percentile. by doing the below partitioning I am able to get my percentiles data right. However my problem is there are duplicates in each row. E.g for each DESC there are multiple duplicates when it is suppose to be only 1 row. Why is this so?

```
row_nums AS 
    (
        SELECT DATE, DESC, NUM, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DATE, DESC ORDER BY NUM ASC) AS Row_Num
        FROM ******
    )
SELECT .................
```

This is the output I get currently: (Where there are duplicate rows being returned - Refer to Row 6 to 8)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/foe7g.png[^]

This is the output I want to achieve: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GkrHP.png[^]

Comment: can you provide the sample data as your syntax looking fine except that date,Desc

Comment: Don't know your data. Maybe this is as easy as `SELECT DISTINCT ...`?

Comment: updated the sample data thanks

Comment: Did you try to simply use `SELECT DISTINCT' ?

Comment: yes I tried without saying but its not working. thanks there is still duplicated rows in it

Answer (score 0):

You can remove duplicate by adding one more INNER query in FROM clause like below:

```
;WTIH row_nums AS 
    (
        SELECT DATE, DESC, NUM, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DATE, DESC   ORDER BY NUM ASC) AS Row_Num
        FROM (
             SELECT your required columns, COUNT(duplicated_rows_columnsname)
             FROM ***
             GROUP BY columnnames
             HAVING COUNT(duplicated_rows_columnsname) = 1
        )
    )
SELECT .................
```

However, You can also remove duplicate row using DISTINCT clause in INNER. query.